# source code visible in the production : create react app

Tags: html, create-react-app

we are using create react app and converted the source js files into chunks. but I can see that chrome inspect source tab shows the actual code. Is this expected behavior ? Or is there any build configuration that I need to configure to that further ? I have attached an image of the result. [image: minified]

Comment: *"(source mapped from ...)"*

Comment: yes. how do I restrict that ? do I further minify the chunk.js ?

Comment: No, you just don't serve the source maps in production (or don't create them at all: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2005).

Comment: 1. Read up on source maps. 2. Look at it and see!

Answer (score 9):

The source code what you see is loaded from the map files as you can see it from the console

[image]

You can remove map files from your production server.

Add `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` in your .env file, so build will not create map files

Comment: It worked. I had this problem when deploying to production by using creat-react-app, I just put this .env in the root and then tested by building it locally and served with `serve -s build`. Then, the code as not there anymore. Thanks!